# Lock out user with maxInvalidPasswordAttempts not work

Tags: asp.net

I try to do research about Lock out users after three unsuccessful attempts without using a database, and I found the answer that use it with SQLMemberShipProvider. I modify th Web.config :

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOnCust" timeout="2880" />
 </authentication>
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
    type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
    connectionStringName="WebDBConnection" 
    maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3" 
    minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
    passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
    applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

But it doesn't work, I don't know why. What modifications do I need to make more?

Comment: maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"  != 3 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.maxinvalidpasswordattempts.aspx

Comment: So are you saying you're not using a database?  Or you are and don't see the field increment as invalid passwords attempts happen?

Comment: @uadrive : I tried that, and testing login 3 times with my own account with the incorrect password, but I still can log in to web page at the 4th time. So I don't know what can I do or see error about that.

Comment: Interesting.  I ran into this problem once before and found the issue was definitely in the web.config.  I will go look at that app and see if I can remember the fix for you.

Comment: @socheata - You should set passwordAttemptWindow="1" minute. Text From MSDN : The default is 10 minutes. If the interval between the current failed attempt and the last failed attempt is greater than the PasswordAttemptWindow property setting, each failed attempt is treated as if it were the **first** failed attempt.

Comment: @AVD - Wouldn't that have the opposite effect.  If you set the attempt window to 1 minute, wouldn't it reset the failed attempts back down if they attempt 1 minute after the last attempt?  Just reading about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478949.aspx.

Comment: @AVD : Thanks for your answer. I tried all the response here but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting your default membership provider to see if that helps.

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOnCust" timeout="2880" />
 </authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
    type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
    connectionStringName="WebDBConnection" 
    maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3" 
    minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
    passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
    applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Also, check to make sure the stored procedures are properly installed, I know I ran into that issue with Oracle, but haven't had many problems when using SQL Server.  Doesn't hurt to check.

Comment: I added this : <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
 But it still have no something effect while I log in fail 3 times :(

Comment: Can you post your login code?  I'm wondering if the issue lies somewhere there.  Are you using the account login MVC generated code with Unit Tests?  If you are, show me the ValidateUser(string userName, string password) method.

Comment: Is it supported by Windows Authentication?

Comment: Do a search for WindowsMembershipProvider and you should find what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My cause was that user had not been approved. After user is approved, than "FailedPasswordAttemptCount" is incremented after each fail attempt.