# ASP.NET Windows Authentication - Set max attempts before redirect to error page?

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication, iis, windows-authentication

When using windows authentication for my web application if someone gets the username/password combination wrong they are prompted to enter their username/password again. This repeats indefinitely.

If possible I would like to be able to redirect them to an error page after 3 incorrect login attemps. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want help writing custom code to implement this or are you asking if there are built in settings that will do it automatically?

Comment: I was hoping I could somehow set up my web.config file to do this.

Comment: not sure on that.  I'll post another way just for the heck of it.

Comment: You can use asp.net membership and set maxInvalidPasswordAttempts. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651068/lock-out-user-with-maxinvalidpasswordattempts-not-work